# What is name/terminology for area in .tif satellite image file which is blank space/not land?

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite, terminology

I have some L2 satellite images from an MSI bundle, and I need to produce a mask over the area in the file which is not the image itself - the black part in the image below.

What is the technical name for this black area generally?

It occurs as the actual satellite image is partially rotated within the file.

[image]

Comment: NoData area https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/nodata-in-raster-datasets.htm.

Comment: null values (NoData)